# how to send \n neutral character in strophe.js

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

To implement keep alive feature for Ejabberd it recommends to send a `\n` character to server.

I'm using strophe.js as the client library. How do I send neutral character from strophe?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to encode the `carriage return` (CR) character. That is, you can use its character entity:  `&#13;`